# Validate a file upload ? JSF

Tags: jsf, file-upload

I would like to validate a file have been selected before the user can proceed, how would i do this ?

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    Upload a text file:
                    <corejsf:upload value="#{user.fileText}"/><br/><br/>

                    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="/submittedText"/>
```

i just want to make sure the user has selected a file, also at this stage would it be possible to validate what type of file is selected I.E. only a .txt ?

Comment: What's this `<corejsf:upload>` tag from your code?

Comment: using primeface upload, the tag i am using is from an example how to upload files using primefaces

Comment: Please edit and improve the question based on feedback. As of now the question can't reasonably be answered.